# jQuery Optimizing Vote Switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, voting-system

I am just quite a bit of a beginner about javascript jQuery, so I'm experimenting them myself and learn from them.

So I have 2 `<label>`s being used for displaying the votes, which is `up votes` and `down votes`. There is no problem for the adding or removing votes, but the switching of votes is the issue (not really an issue).

The structure of the votes in the html is:

```html
<label id="up_vote"></label>
<label id="down_vote"></label>
```

The values are retrieved from the database and I user `innerHTML` to insert the data between the `<label>` tags. Once the user clicks the `<label>`, either the `up_vote` or the `down_vote`, the update request is sent through ajax and updates the vote counts, and once it is successfully executed, the value inside the `<label>` will be incremented by one, as well as the removing of vote, it will be decremented. And a `voted` class will be added once the user votes.

My javascript looks like these:

```js
$("#up_vote, #down_vote").click(function(e) {
  var voteCount = document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML;
  var action;
  var value;

  if ($("#up_vote").hasClass("voted") || $("#down_vote").hasClass("voted")) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("voted")) {
      action = "remove_vote";
      setValue();
    } else {
      action = "switch_vote";
      setValue();
    }
  } else {
    action = "add_vote";
    setValue();
  }

  function setValue() {
    if (e.target.id === "up_vote") {
      value = 1;
    } else if (e.target.id === "down_vote") {
      value = -1;
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "votes.php",
    data: , //it includes the user session id, the post id, and the action and values for doing the specific functions (i just didn't put it here, just giving the logic on what does my code looks like
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      if (msg === "vote_added") {
        document.getElementById.innerHTML = parseInt(voteCount) + 1;
        $("#" + e.target.id).addClass("voted");
      } else if (msg === "vote_removed") {
        // the same function of the vote_added message, but instead, it decrements the value and removes the "voted" class
      } else if (msg === "vote_switched") {
        // these is the part that i want to achieve, but coding it seems a bit long (just my thought)
      } else if (msg === "vote_exist") {
        // these is a, some sort of notifying the user that the he/she already votes the specific post
      }
    }
  })
})
```

As on what you see on the javascipt, it sends an `action` and `value` (which will specify if it is `up vote` or `down vote`, which will be used to do specific functions inside the php. It will then echo out the message that will be used once the query is executed successfully.

(On the last condition, `vote_exist`, is used for security check. While I'm testing something out, removing the `class="voted"` (which notifies that the user already voted) inside Inspector window, clicking these back will increment the vote count again, which removes the restrictions, so I added a validation function inside the php before the user votes for doubled security check. Hope that these can help for others.)

My concern is about the 3rd condition, which is the switching of votes. For example, the user already up votes, and then he/she wants to  down vote. There is no problem for the queries, just for the javascript part. I have an idea though, by using the same functions inside the `vote_added` and `vote_removed`, where, when clicked, will target id will be incremented at the same time the other one will be decremented, also adds a `voted` class to the target id and removes the other one.

How can I do these in a shorter way?

(Sorry for the long post, just trying to explain on what does the code does.)

Comment: Give TL;DR; will be good.

Comment: *"How can I do these in a shorter way?"* - You seem to be saying that your current code achieves the desired effect, but that you would like to optimise it? If so, this question would be better placed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Zange-chan A kind of summary of the question.